# Is there a Clang diagnostic that is only a note?

Tags: clang, diagnostics

[Clang has several kinds of diagnostics](http://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html), of which the three main kinds are errors, warnings, and notes.

Notes usually accompany certain warnings and errors, such as duplicate definitions:

```
error: conflicting types for 'square'
static double square(double x) {
              ^
note: previous declaration is here
static int square(int x);
           ^
```

What I want to know is, does Clang have any diagnostics—especially for Objective-C or C, but I'll settle for C++ if I have to—that consist of *only* a note, with no associated error or warning?

Answer (score 5):

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#the-diagnostic-kinds-td-files says:

> These severities are mapped into a smaller set (the Diagnostic::Level
>   enum, {Ignored, Note, Warning, Error, Fatal}) of output levels by the
>   diagnostics subsystem based on various configuration options. Clang
>   internally supports a fully fine grained mapping mechanism that allows
>   you to map almost any diagnostic to the output level that you want.
>   The only diagnostics that cannot be mapped are NOTEs, which always
>   follow the severity of the previously emitted diagnostic and ERRORs,
>   which can only be mapped to Fatal (it is not possible to turn an error
>   into a warning, for example).

So unfortunately no; you can't do that without hacking Clang itself. Notes are intended only for linking to other diagnostics. I'd file a bug with the LLVM tracker; this would definitely be useful functionality.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what use do you think they may have?